# How can I get a value from database that has the soonest time to current time?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I keep getting a NullPointerException when I try this query:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("collection", new String[] { "SELECT interval WHERE MIN(time) FROM collection" }, null, null,
                   null, null, null); // This is where the NPE is. 
           cursor.moveToFirst();  //ADD THIS!
           Integer collectionInterval = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Is my select query right or the way I'm setting this up?

Basically above I want to select an interval where the soonest time to current time from a table. How can I do that?

Comment: It's tricky to diagnose a NullPointerException when there is no stack trace provided. If you would rather not provide the full information due to giving away some of your code structure, then for the purpose of this diagnosis, only the stack trace within (i.e. deeper than) the line shown above is needed.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT SELECT interval FROM collection WHERE time = (SELECT MIN(time) FROM collection) FROM collection  after following @Elliott Frisch query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a query, `FROM` comes before `WHERE`. Also, I think you need an equality test there

```
SELECT interval FROM collection WHERE time = (SELECT MIN(time) FROM collection)
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT SELECT interval FROM collection WHERE time = (SELECT MIN(time) FROM collection) FROM collection

Comment: Do you have two SELECT statements at the beginning of your query? Remove one.